# How to clear text input?

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've been trying to fix this issue for a while now, none of the existing questions help. I'm using [the node implementation of Selenium WebDriver](https://github.com/mojotech/node-selenium-webdriver), version *^4.0.0-alpha.1* and testing it on Chrome using the latest ChromeDriver.

I'm trying to clear the text of an `<input/>`, whose `type="email"`. WebDriver has a [built in command](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebElement.html#clear) for this, but when I execute it the input doesn't clear (and there's no error):

```
// This populates the text field, no problem
driver.findElement(By.id("model-auth-email")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");

// This is executed without error, but nothing happens, text field isn't cleared
driver.findElement(By.id("model-auth-email")).clear();
```

I can't use the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> & <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> method since I'm using a Mac and it would be <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>. And ChromeDriver has had (still unresolved) issues supporting the native OSX <kbd>CMD</kbd> button input for like 6 years, according the various threads I could find.

I could also do something like loop <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> inputs until it's cleared, though that's pretty hacky.

Any ideas on why `.clear()` is silently not working?

Comment: Are you sure you posted the correct github link?

Comment: @shkaper yes that's the correct one

Answer (score 4):

What seems to be working for us is to:

1. Use JavaScript to execute the [`select()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select) method of the `<input>` element.
2. Then use Selenium WebDriver to send a <kbd>BACKSPACE</kbd> key.

Here's a `clear` function that will do just that:

```
async function clear(drv, web_elt) {
  await drv.executeScript(elt => elt.select(), web_elt);
  await web_elt.sendKeys(Key.BACK_SPACE);
}
```

Whereby:

- `drv` is an instance of [`WebDriver`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebDriver.html)
- `web_elt` is an instance of [`WebElement`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/index_exports_WebElement.html)
- The anonymous function in `executeScript` is stringified and receives the `<input>` element wrapped in `web_elt` as a parameter

Find below a demo and the full code for it.

---

*This is running on Node.js 11 with `selenium-webdriver` v4.

Make sure your chromedriver is in your PATH then run `node index.js`*

[image]

```
// index.js
const path = require('path');
const wd = require('selenium-webdriver');
const {Key} = wd;

const driver =
  (new wd.Builder)
    .forBrowser(wd.Browser.CHROME)
    .build();

async function clear(drv, web_elt) {
  await drv.executeScript(elt => elt.select(), web_elt);
  await web_elt.sendKeys(Key.BACK_SPACE);
}

async function run(drv) {
  await drv.get('file://' + path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
  await drv.sleep(1000);
  await clear(drv, drv.findElement({css: 'input'}));
  await drv.sleep(1000);
  await clear(drv, drv.findElement({css: 'textarea'}));
  await drv.sleep(1000);
  await drv.quit();
}

run(driver);
```

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<html>
  <body>
    <p>
      <input type="text" value="Hello World!"/>
    </p>
    <p>
      <textarea cols="30" rows="10">Hello World!</textarea>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've tried so many different methods, but this is the only one that's worked for me on Mac + Chrome. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and .clear() or CTRL+'a' didn't work for me,
this one worked perfectly:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", text_input)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Webdriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver_exports_WebElement.html#clear) document, **findElement** will return a promise, so you can try:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("model-auth-email"))
  .then((el) => {
  el.clear()
  })
  .catch(e => {
    throw e; 
  });
```

Comment: Yeah I've tried it like that originally, I'm not using the promise syntax in my question cos I set my tests up to work in a slightly different way, using async/await and/or chaining a bunch and only having `.then()` on the last. But yes, tried your suggestion and it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Is "model-auth-email" correct? Maybe you can try to find this element with xpath or css selector...

Comment: It's right, because it finds the element in the first place to populate it. It can add the text to it, just doesn't clear it